# Is it possible to use Google Datastore from a local application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are developping an application that uploads files from our database to Google drive. We also would like to store data on the Google datastore during this upload. This is not a web application and the upload functionallity will be triggered when a new file is added to our database.

My question is: Is it possible to access the Google Datastore from our local application? Because when I read about the Google App Engine it's seems like it works only for webapplications on the Google servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are hoping to do with this data. As you say, the GAE datastore is for GAE applications only. So even if you store the data, you won't be able to access it without having a web app running on GAE. (Note that there is a ["remote API"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi), but it only works alongside an existing GAE application - also it's not very efficient and isn't really for production use.)

However, there is a separate product called [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-datastore/) that uses similar technology to the GAE app and can be accessed via REST, so your desktop app could create and read data there.

Comment: So I would not be able to store the data, since I don't have a GAE application... Ok thanks for the explanation and the Google Cloud Datastore suggestion!

Comment: Actually you can do other things with the remote_api (though the cloud datastore is now a better option).  I had a project many years ago (2009) that pushed content from Plone directly to the datastore via appengine.  The plone instance used the remote_api to update content directly.